# Regular expression groups with one or more characters

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match lines that don't begin with a given pattern.  If this pattern is a single letter, it's easy enough, e.g `^[^ABCD].*` matches `Frog` but not `Dog` or `Cat`.

But I want to ignore a single letter or a two-letter combo and can't figure out the right syntax.  For example, I want to match `Frog` and `Cow` but not `Dog` or `Cat`.  I've tried this expression `^[^(D|Ca)].*` but it only matches `Frog` (i.e. it ignores `Cow`).

Comment: You require lookaheads..though here it can be done without it but it will be lengthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require lookaheads

```
^(?!D|Ca).*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tU1mU2/2)**